# Windows API reserved parameters

Tags: windows, winapi, parameters

I was wondering why some functions have some parameters that must be set to NULL because of "reserved parameters". For example:

```
LONG WINAPI RegQueryValueEx(
  __in         HKEY hKey,
  __in_opt     LPCTSTR lpValueName,
  __reserved   LPDWORD lpReserved,
  __out_opt    LPDWORD lpType,
  __out_opt    LPBYTE lpData,
  __inout_opt  LPDWORD lpcbData
);
```

I can't understand why lpReserved exists? I mean, if it's reserved why put it, wouldn't be simpler to directly omit it?

Thanks! :) (pay no attention to my English please..)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I see at least two reasons.

One would be that this parameter is reserved for future use and possible functionality extension.  Making sure it's set to `NULL` could guarantee to some degree that in the future, when the new functionality has been added it won't break older programs.

Second possible reason would be that this parameter could actually be used internally as part of private API and public part of API dictates to set this parameter to `NULL`.

Why not to omit it altogether?  It's much easier later to extend functionality of the system without changing the interface.  It stays binary and source code compatible with the old API and does not require rebuilding of the older software.

Comment: There's one other reason you missed: When the API was created, the lpReserved field was used for something else, over time the field became unnecessary or unwanted.  Instead of changing the API signature (which would break all existing clients) the API owner simply chose to make the field 'reserved'.

Comment: @Larry: Thanks, you are right.  To be precise though, I did not say these are **all** the reasons.  Do you mind I add this to the answer?

Comment: My gut feeling is that @Larry's explanation is the most common reason for these parameters.

Comment: @Steve I was hoping that @Larry would come back and elaborate given his intimate knowledge of Win32

Comment: @David: I don't have any good stories actually on this particular example.  But I did spelunk one other example a couple of years ago: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2007/02/07/the-sad-story-of-cogetmalloc.aspx

Comment: +1 I was always wondering about this. Good question & answer. and Larry's comment.

Comment: @Larry, But in that case, we don't need to set the parameter as NULL. Isn't it? Many api documents describe 'This parameter is reserved and must be NULL.' Why?

Comment: @Benjamin: Windows has a lot of support for running old apps. If you pass non-NULL for a parameter that has to be NULL today, you might identify yourself as one of those old apps and may get a lot of treatment that you didn't expect.

Comment: The "Not Used" parameter attribute is a more frank exposition of Larry's answer.