# What is the arg "reserved" of jni function JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved)?

Tags: java-native-interface

In jni.h, there defined

```
JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved);
```

What's the use of parameter **reserved** ?

Comment: Not JNI-specific, but this answer is on-target: [Windows API reserved parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392454/windows-api-reserved-parameters)

Comment: thanks. so, although it seems useless now, perhaps the JNI designer has not optimized it, or it is reserved for a future function.